# Do you have to worry about event duplication when using the "on" function in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

On projects using older versions of jQuery, I sometimes see things like this:

```
$(window).unbind("scroll").scroll(infiniteScroll);
```

I believe this is to prevent duplication of event handlers.

Is this necessary with the newer `on` function? In other words, is it ever necessary to use `off` before using `on`?

```
$(window).off("scroll").on("scroll", infiniteScroll);
```

Or is it safe to simply use `on` even if it might be bound multiple times?

```
$(window).on("scroll", infiniteScroll);
```

Comment: Same concerns apply. Now, if you use the `$(container).on('event', 'selector', function() {...})` version, you could probably pick a container such that you would only have to do the binding once, eliminating the problem.

Comment: If your code logic is clean, you shouldn't have to unbind any event except for very specific case

Comment: I also had this situation 2-3 times when I had to use _unbind()_.

Comment: If you bind an event multiple times (regardless of how it was bound: `.click()`, `.on('click')`, or the old `.live()` or `.bind()` methods), that function will be called multiple times.  `.on` does not magically fix this issue.  The "issue" is probably loading a JS file multiple times, or using a plugin that has to override events.

Comment: You should structure your code better so you don't have to call `off()`. Especially try to avoid calling `off('event')` without specifying which handler to detach or you end up detaching all handlers on that event.

Comment: There are several comments about code structure here, but I think this question is really independent of code structure. Of course, the best policy is to make sure that there are not multiple binding attempts in the first place (this is in fact what I'm doing in my application), but I think the question is still valid as-is.

Comment: @David It probably would have been best to just try it.  You're not going to break the internet ;)  http://jsfiddle.net/dz9qR/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.on()` on its own does not solve the problem, however, it does provide namespaces, which does solve the problem more robustly.

```
$(window)
    .off(".mynamespacethatisunique")
    .on("scroll.mynamespacethatisunique", infiniteScroll);
```